# Git - apply change made in the difftool

Tags: git, git-diff, git-difftool

I'm sure this is very basic, but I've read the docs, and still can't figure it out.

I have two branches, and I need to merge some changes in a couple of files in manually (don't ask). I am viewing the files side by side, with the difference highlighted, with:

`git difftool branch1 branch2 -- path_to_file`

This allows me to copy everything I need into the file that will be remaining (which is in branch1 fwiw), but the file is some long filename in /tmp/. I don't know how to actually save my edits to the file that I am editing (I'm using vim as the difftool, and I have set `noreadonly`, the issue is that it's a different file (something in /tmp/, as I said).

There are only a couple of changes, and I could just manually edit the file in branch1, but I'm sure that git diff must allow me to do this, and I'd like to learn to do it properly.

Comment: @RomainValeri Yes, basically, everything is a mess, and only this file needs to be merged. The branches differ in other ways, but only this file needs merging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can just force vim to overwrite the original file when it saves... I guess this works fine.

Comment: As a slightly invalid generalization, `git diff` compares two commits, and `git difftool` takes such a comparison— *not* the actual files, just the comparison—and feeds it through some sort of display tool that the user prefers. This is not *meant* to edit files. You can do exactly what you are doing, but that's a bit like using a wrench as a hammer: it works, but it's the wrong tool. Unfortunately, in this case there's no single right tool, though using `vimdiff` directly might be easier (just use `git show` to extract the not-current-branch version of the file, to a temp name).

Comment: @torek that makes sense, thank you. I guess what i was looking for was the functionality that the merge tool/process gives, but not in the context of a merge!

Comment: @torek That said, how would I get vimdiff to show the difference between the same file in different branches?

Comment: I don't actually use vimdiff (I just read diffs directly, normally...) but as I understand it, you run `vimdiff <path1> <path2>`.  To get the version of `path2` from the commit identified by `branch1`, use `git show branch1:path2`.  To get the version from the commit identified by `branch2`, use `git show branch2:path2`.  Redirect these to temporary files so that vimdiff can see them.

Comment: Note also that if you want a proper three-way merge, which requires *three* files—merge base, left / ours, and right / theirs "sides"—you can use `git merge-file`. As before you'll want to `git show` each of those committed contents to a temporary file.

Answer (score 0):

A function can help. Tested with ZSH and may require adaption for other shells. Can be used on the whole repo or a path can also be specified to narrow down the scope.

```
gitdifftoolbranch() {
    TARGET_BRANCH_REMOTE="origin/master"

    if [ -z "$1" ]; then
        local files=("${(f)$(git diff --name-only --line-prefix=$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)/ ${TARGET_BRANCH_REMOTE}...)}")
    else
        local files=("${(f)$(git diff --name-only --line-prefix=$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)/ ${TARGET_BRANCH_REMOTE}... -- "$1")}")
    fi

    for file in ${files}
    do
        git difftool ${TARGET_BRANCH_REMOTE} -- ${file}
    done
}
```